# Generic Extension Method To Count Descendants

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I've created a extension method to count every available descendant starting from a single, given key.

The data is a flat list, there's is no hierarchical structure. (Well, not entirely true. There is an hierarchy in the data-model, but not in the list itself)

```
self-reference      parent-reference   some other members
10045     =>        0                   ..
10046     =>        10045               ..
10044     =>        10063               ..
10061     =>        10044               ..
10063     =>        10046               ..
10064     =>        10046               ..
10021     =>        10061               ..
10028     =>        10000               ..
10030     =>        10000               ..
10031     =>        10000               ..
10000     =>        10000               ..
```

As an example, counting the descendant of the entry with the self-reference number 10046 would result in 6.

Let's take 10021 as an possible related entry to entry 10046, for example.

> 10021 refers to 10061, 10061 refers to 10044, 10044 refers to 10063,
>   10063 refers to 10046 
>   => related!

---

My extension method is actually split up in two different methods.

```
public static int CountDescendants<TSource, T>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    T startKey, 
    Func<TSource, T> selfReference,
    Func<TSource, T> parentReference)
{
    if(source == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    return Count(source, startKey, selfReference, parentReference);
}
```

`startKey` defines our filter, the key we're looking for. In the example above I've used

> 10046

`selfReference` defines a unique key a dataset can be identified with.

`parentReference` defines a unique key which refers to another dataset.

The actual algorithm looks like this.

```
private static int Count<TSource, T>(
            IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
            T key, 
            Func<TSource, T> selfReference, 
            Func<TSource, T> parentReference)
{
    // hash-map + .Where is faster than using IEnumerable + .Where
    ReadOnlyDictionary<T, T> consolidatedSource = 
        new ReadOnlyDictionary<T, T>(source.ToDictionary(selfReference, parentReference));
    int count = 0;

    // to keep track of every reference which is somehow related to "key"
    HashSet<T> keys = new HashSet<T> {
        key
    };

    // using a stack instead of recurison
    Stack<KeyValuePair<T, T>> stack = new Stack<KeyValuePair<T, T>>();

    // get all first level entries with the given key
    foreach(KeyValuePair<T,T> item in consolidatedSource.Where(x => x.Value.Equals(key))) {
        stack.Push(item);
    }

    // using .Any over .Count because we don't care how many items we have but rather that the stack is not empty
    while (stack.Any()) {
        KeyValuePair<T, T> current = stack.Pop();

        if (keys.Contains(current.Value)) {
            count++;
            keys.Add(current.Key);

            // get all first level entries with the new key
            foreach (KeyValuePair<T, T> item in consolidatedSource.Where(x => x.Value.Equals(current.Key) && !x.Key.Equals(current.Key))){
                stack.Push(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

The method can be called like this

`this.AllProfiles.CountDescendants(CurrentProfile.Ref, x => x.Ref, x => x.ParentRef);`

Is stuff like using a Dictionary to speed up things micro-optimization which I shouldn't worry about? Personally, wherever I can impact performance, I try to get the best out of it. Or at least not make it any worse.

Also, I'm not entirely sure if there are any constraints I can apply to the generic types. I don't think there's one that actually fits and is needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to return a tree structure, and then have properties like Count on each Node?

Comment: Using a flat structure greatly simplifies other parts of the application, especially when working with databases. Creating a tree structure would be a way but I wouldn't have any use for. I think it would be 'too much' if I created one just to count the nodes afterwards.

Comment: Understandable... I just figured a method to convert this flat structure to tree might be very reusable :)

Comment: Is it a static read only list, or is it dynamic (delete/add)? And what is the expected average size of it?

Answer (score 6):

Peter already pointed out the main problem with your code: you're doing linear searches when looking for child-nodes, which will blow up to \$O(n^2)\$ for worst-case inputs (very deep trees). Indeed, a lookup table that maps a parent ID to child IDs is much more efficient, and ensures that your method remains \$O(n)\$ for all sorts of input.

Another problem is that your method does not guard against cyclic inputs - it'll run indefinitely. You may want to throw an exception instead, or otherwise prevent the start item from being added to the stack again. It's also a good idea to document this behavior.

Other notes:

- There's no need to perform input validation in a separate method here: `Count` does not use `yield`, so the input validation will be performed immediately. Note that a modern alternative is to move the `yield`ing part to a local function instead of to a separate method.
- When throwing argument-related exceptions, it's better to use `nameof(parameterName)` instead of `"parameterName"`. This lets the compiler protect you against typos, and works well with code refactoring tools.
- I would rename `T` to `TKey`, `selfReference` to `keySelector` and `parentReference` to `parentKeySelector`. I think that better describes their purpose, and it's consistent with other Linq methods.
- Use `var` to cut down on type name repetition: `var variableName = new LongTypeName(...);` is equivalent to `LongTypeName variableName = new LongTypeName(...);`.
- As Peter already mentioned, there's no need for that `keys` set: you're only adding items with a known parent ID to the stack, so there's no point in verifying whether their parent ID is known.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible infinite loop. Data-wise it shouldn't be possible, but I'v added a guard. The only reason I've separated those methods because I didn't want the actual algorithm to do 'too much' and mainly because I've been doing it with other methods as well. Using ```nameof``` is a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Good point on the cycle detection, but then maybe `keys` is useful after all. It's certainly the most straightforward way of detecting a cycle.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> public static int CountDescendants<TSource, T>(
>     this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
>     T startKey, 
>     Func<TSource, T> selfReference,
>     Func<TSource, T> parentReference)
> {
>     if(source == null) {
>         throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
>     }
>
>     return Count(source, startKey, selfReference, parentReference);
> }
> ```

Thumbs up for doing the validation in a non-coroutine method, although I wonder why `source` is the only argument which needs validation.

---

> ```
>     // hash-map + .Where is faster than using IEnumerable + .Where
>     ReadOnlyDictionary<T, T> consolidatedSource = 
>         new ReadOnlyDictionary<T, T>(source.ToDictionary(selfReference, parentReference));
> ```

Firstly, why `ReadOnlyDictionary`? This isn't exposed outside this method, and within the method you should able to trust yourself not to do anything nasty with it.

Secondly, I think the comment is indicative of a misunderstanding. Hash-map + `.TryGetValue` is faster than `IEnumerable` + `.Where`, but a linear search through a hash-map is no faster than a linear search through a list.

What you probably want to use here is `source.ToLookup(parentReference)`. That *will* give an asymptotic performance improvement.

---

> ```
>     Stack<KeyValuePair<T, T>> stack = new Stack<KeyValuePair<T, T>>();
> ```

If you have C# 7 then it would probably be nicer to use `Stack<(T foo, T bar)>` with suitable names. The ability to have names at all is part of the point here.

Although, FWIW, I'm not convinced that you need anything more than `Stack<T>`, and I don't think `keys` is necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already added the validation for the other arguments but forgot to update my post. I used the ```ReadOnlyDictionary``` out of habit because I usually explicitly declare read-only types as such, but I followed your suggestion to use ```.ToLookup``` instead. The ```HashSet``` is useless as you mentioned, I removed it. I also changed the stack to be of the type ```T```. Thanks for your notes, they really helped!